# Kafka current offset internals

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Can somebody explain, how Kafka's current offset mechanism works from the consumer's point of view? I have a huge topic (several gigabytes), divided into 2 partitions. And in some business cases (rare ones), I need to choose random N records within partition and read it.
My colleague says, that Kafka consumer does not know anything about offsets, it just receives a bunch of records on every `poll()` with offset, attached to every record as meta-information. I.e. the "seek" mechanism works as follows: consumer asks records and ignores it until target offset has been met.
Is it true? In my understanding such a "rewinding" is a wasting of consumer resources and internet traffic. I think there MUST be a way to point at a specific offset, so that a broker could send the record with that specific offset immediately on `poll()` without that kinda "spinloop" stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** seek to a specific offset. But it's the consumer group / offsets topic that stores that information, not the consumer itself.

Hopping around to "random" offsets is indeed not efficient.

Size of topic doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you give more detailed explanation, please? I don't get into "but it's the consumer group/offset topic that store that information, not the consumer itself". As far as I know, there are **current offset** and **commited offset**. The latter one stored on a broker node in the internal topic, and have important role of "bookmark" of place to start from, when rebalancing is triggered. But there is no link (in my current understanding) with current offset - commited offset gives only a "start point", and it looks like it is a consumer responsible for sending the current offset.

Comment: Consumers are responsible for committing offsets, but that could be any offset, not "current". Consumers are stateless